# QListWidget item text is not returning with If statement

Tags: python, pyside2, nuke

I have a QListWidget. I am running this function on itemClicked, and this function is also called from different part of my program. So this function has optional argument cutrrentItemText. for some reason my code is not working. Check below example.

```py
def loadSomething(self,currentItemText=None):
    if not currentItemText:
        item = self.listWidget.currentItem()
        currentItemText = item.text()
    print currentItemText

#result from above code
<PySide2.QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem object at 0x7f910b112e60>
```

instead of item text it assigns item object. Here is code without if statement which is working like charm.

```py
def loadSomething(self,currentItemText=None):
    #if not currentItemText:
    item = self.listWidget.currentItem()
    currentItemText = item.text()
    print currentItemText

#result of this give currentItems text
```

I am wondering where I am making mistake. Can any one tell me whats wrong in this code??

Note: I am trying this in Foundry nuke. Trying a custom python panel.

**Update:**
In my main widget init i have this to connect itemClicked event

```py
self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect( self.loadSomething )
```

**Resolved:**

I just realized, itemClicked event sends current item object while call back. so first argument should be item,

```py
def loadSomething(self,item,currentItemText=None)
```

above change worked

Comment: I just realized, itemClicked event sends current item object while call back. so first argument should be item, so 
```def loadSomething(self,item,currentItemText=None)
``` worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (I tested it in NukeX 12.0v3 on Catalina):

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui
import nuke

def loadSomething(currentItemText=None):
    if not currentItemText:
        item = QListWidget.currentItem()
        currentItemText = item.text()
    print currentItemText

loadSomething(currentItemText="Some")
```

[image]